# Can I replace "would" with "will" in this sentence "how would that benefit me."?

Tags: difference

I am watching a movie in which two people fight with two zombies. One of them says "Do you want to switch?" and 
other says "How would that benefit me?"
In the second sentence can I replace "would" with "will"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however the word "would" is a "lets just say this happened" or "might" but "not guaranteed" situation. When you change it to say "will", it changes the story to mean something that is going to happen .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. 
But, the meaning of the sentence, which paraphrase looks like that 'How do you imagine my benefit from switching ? ' will change to the meaning of 'What is your sure knowledge about my benefit from switching?'